# Refresh KML stylesheet in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have an externally defined stlysheet, named style.kml which defines the different styles I use in my maps. Recently, I added a new style, defined identically to the other styles, just with a different icon, but it wont load into Google Earth.

The style looks like:

```
Style id="red-dsl">
    <LabelStyle>
        <color>ffffffff</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <scale>0.8</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <IconStyle>
        <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.05" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
        <Icon>
            <href>URL/crimson-d.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>7f1f1fff</color>
        <width>2.0</width>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>401f1fbf</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

Where URL is our private URL, and is being called with

```
$placemark->styleUrl = "style.kml#red-dsl";
```

I know it is assigning correctly, because if I use one of the older style-types, then the icon appears correctly.

I have tried re-compiling the kml file, deleting/refreshing the cache, but no luck so far.

How can I refresh/reload the KML stylesheet for my Google Earth maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the map everyday for a week, it started working with the right icon after 9+ days. Im not sure what changed, but it seems like leaving it for a considerable length of time will fix the problem.